# nodejs express client Cannot GET /xxx.html before accessing main

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the following server side code:

```
var app = express();
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.redirect('/main');
});
app.get('/main', function (req, res) {
    var d = new Date();
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/main.html'));
    Info(req.ip + ' - Session to main.html built successfully! ');
    app.use(express.static(__dirname));
});
```

Also there are some other html files in the same directory, e.g. xxx.html.
I found the following behavior that confuses, if I build a new session, try to access localhost:7778/xxx.html, the client cannot get: Cannot GET /xxx.html:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

On the other hand, after accessed localhost:7778/, and then try to access localhost:7778/xxx.html, will succeed.

Can anyone explain the behavior? Can I set the localhost/xxx.html be able to directly accessed?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move `app.use(express.static(__dirname));` outside of the `app.get('/main', ...)` handler:

```
var app = express();
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.redirect('/main');
});
app.get('/main', function (req, res) {
    var d = new Date();
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/main.html'));
    Info(req.ip + ' - Session to main.html built successfully! ');
});
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
```

According to Express [document](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.use):

> **app.use([path,] callback [, callback...])**
>
> Mounts the specified middleware function or functions at the specified path

The specified middleware (`express.static`) should be declared as itself, and be executed once the server is started. It should not be executed as part of logic in `GET /main`'s handler.